# cannot connect to some web site through pptp vpn

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, ping, routing

I have a PPTP VPN service on a Ubuntu server, and when I connect to it, I found I cannot connect to some web site, e.g. live.com.

I tried to ping the web site, but failed. So I tried **`tracert`** on windows, and below is the output.

Tracing route to live.com [65.55.206.154]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

```
    1   784 ms   626 ms   821 ms  172.16.1.3
    2   513 ms   631 ms   964 ms  basil.vpsville.com [67.227.82.10]
    3   493 ms   483 ms     *     gw.mcom-colocationamerica.com [208.64.231.81]
    4   575 ms   496 ms   401 ms  tge4-1.cr2.lax.multacom.com [208.64.231.6]
    5   434 ms   379 ms   467 ms  microsoft.com.any2ix.coresite.com [206.223.143.143]
    6   592 ms   584 ms   941 ms  xe-0-0-0-0.lax-96cbe-1b.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.47.5]
    7   540 ms   528 ms   477 ms  ge-1-3-0-0.ash-64cb-1a.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.43.8]
    8   561 ms   695 ms   542 ms  ge-7-1-0-0.blu-64c-1a.ntwk.msn.net [207.46.43.17]
->  9   514 ms   800 ms   632 ms  10.22.100.1
    10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

The 9th record is very interesting, it does not seem to be a valid public internet address.

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this kind of network problem. I hope some can help me here.

thanks,
David

Comment: I'm not sure what the title has to do with the question. Your issue occurs on the 10th hop, why do you need more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this link

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162326

Scroll down to TRACERT Synatax to configure more than the 30 default hops in the command.

.

Comment: At the moment, this post is essentially only a link. To make sure the answer remains useful even if the link breaks, please edit it to include the relevant information. (Your answer was discovered in [an effort to repair or remove old link-only answers](http://meta.superuser.com/q/11113/380318).)

Comment: I have never had a Microsoft link break.

Comment: I have - there are boatloads of broken TechNet links on MS blogs. KB's probably are good, but it wouldn't hurt to include a sample command in the answer.

Comment: Mine is not a tecknet link. Fee free to edit my answer.